# Android 5.0 (Lollipop) music equalizer?

Tags: settings, music, 5.0-lollipop, equalizer

First of all, I'm rooted. So since I have Android 5.0 on my Nexus 5 I wonder if there still exists the option to change the music equalizer.

In KitKat it was like:

[image: Music Effects Control Panel]

I wasn't able to find any option like this in the settings, maybe someone of you knows how to get this. I don't want to use the Google Play music equalizer.

Comment: Possible workaround: uninstall/disable other equalisers

Answer (score 4):

That option is removed in Lollipop. If you want to use other equalizer, you have to disable default equalizer from **Settings -> Applications-> All -> MusicFx -> Disable**.

When you opens the equalizer from music player, it will open a chooser by showing other equalizers in it.

Answer (score 0):

A known issue, wait for XPosed framework to be stable on lollipop, and someone will create a memory patch... 
Or for limited experience, VLC seems to have a built-in equalizer that actually works... 
[not a sponsor... ;) ]

Answer (score -1):

Go to applications settings and select all applicationa. Find the MusicFX application clear the Application data for this application and then install other Equlizer from play market. After that when you start music player and select equalizer option new equalizer will be opened.
It was tested on Equalizer FX and it works for me :)

Comment: Tried it with viper4android (best eq I know) and it doesn't seem to work maybe the drivers aren't supporting 5.0....

Comment: It seems android 5 does not support change sound for global output. So you have to start equalizer from music player. And some equalizers does not support change sound effects for specific output stream.

Answer (score -1):

Use AIMP work great... No root need.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for posting a suggestion. Could you expand upon this a little? What's AIMP? Is it an app? Could you add a link to it, and explain how it helps?